# How to hide a parent div if an inner div has a certain class, with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so say I have many divs. Some of the divs, the children have one class, other divs the children have a different class.

I want to hide only the divs which have a child with a certain class.

For example,

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="kulkul">
        <div class="childA">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="lalala">
        <div class="childB">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="kulkul">
        <div class="childA">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="lalala">
        <div class="childA">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="kulkul">
        <div class="childB">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="lalala">
        <div class="childA">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now above, let's say that I only want to hide the parent divs which have a child div with the class `.childB`

This can't be done with CSS as far as I know (CSS3 anyway), because CSS doesn't allow you to style the parent div, only a child div. And the parent `.mainDiv` divs (the ones I want to hide) are all exactly the same.

So that leaves javascript.

Using the example above, how can I hide all the `.mainDiv` divs which contain a child div with the class `.childB`?

Comment: You using jQuery or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HIDING PARENT ELEMENT based on its direct descendant

```
//Update the **sample-element-to-hide** with whatever you wanted to use as a child class with the parent element you wanted to hide e.g., 'childB'
var elementToHideList = document.getElementsByClassName("sample-element-to-hide");
for (var i = elementToHideList.length; i--;)
    elementToHideList[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

HIDING PARENT ELEMENT based on its child element.

```
//Solution for the OP
//Update the **childB** with whatever you wanted to use as a child class with the parent element you wanted to hide.
//Note that this would only works if the parent element has a **className** mainDiv. You can change mainDiv with your own parent className.

$('.classB').closest('.mainDiv').hide();
```

Comment: no I do not want to hide an element with a class name. I want to hide the **parent** div which *can't* be defined by class name since all the parents have the same class.

Comment: @agvr3 see updated notes. The code hides the parent div depending on the child element class which I believe in your example 'classB'

Comment: It is **not** a direct descendant. Updated question with more code to clarify.

Comment: that being said, I suggest you use a little jQuery. See updated answer.

Comment: could you include a fiddle of what have you tried? It works fine with me :)

Comment: this part only, worked! `$('.classB').closest('.mainDiv').hide();` what this line of code did, is that when a `.mainDiv` div contaned an inner div which has the class `.classB`, it ***removed*** the `.mainDiv` div from the page. PERFECT! A+

Comment: Grats! I'll leave the above code for a small reference to others. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with pure javascript:

```js
var elementsChildB = document.getElementsByClassName("childB")
for(var i = 0 ; i < elementsChildB.length ; i++){
  elementsChildB[i].parentNode.style.display = "none" ; 
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childB">
      b
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childB">
      b
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>
```

Or with Jquery:

```js
$(".childB").parent().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childB">
      b
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childB">
      b
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="childA">
      a
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that method only hides immediate parent. I need to hide a specific parent.

Comment: Ah ok, you can use: 
    $(".childB").parents(".mainDiv").hide() 
or
 $(".childB").closest(".mainDiv").hide()

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you could use the following selector. This will hide all `mainDiv` containing `childB` but not  `mainDiv` that contain other elements or `childB` without a `mainDiv`  as its parent (in whichever level , by the use of `closest` - https://api.jquery.com/closest/ ) :

```
 $(".childB").closest(".mainDiv").hide();
```

Fiddle:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".childB").closest(".mainDiv").hide();

});
```

```css
.childB {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.childA {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.mainDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childB">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  PARENT
  <div class="childA">Don't hide
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  PARENT
  <div class="childB">To be hidden
  </div>
</div>


<div class="mainDiv">
  This contains a child A which contains a child B: <br />
  <div class="childA">It is a child A
    <div class="childB">To be hidden
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="childB">Should not be hidden
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't hide `.mainDiv`, it only hides `.childB`. How can i hide the whole `.mainDiv` when it contains a child with class `.childB`?

Comment: again this new update did not hide the `.mainDiv` div (like the other answer did) but only the child.

Comment: @agvr3 Now I understood your problem, try this new piece of code

Comment: someone else already gave your edited answer. and yes it works as i had already accepted their answer that was exactly the same. so thank you. although you did add additional notes on `.closest` query which was helpful so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript Method**

```
var childB = document.getElementsByClassName("childB");
for(var e = 0; e <= childB.length; e++){
  childB[e].parentNode.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

**JQuery Method**

```
$('.childB').parent().hide();
```

Comment: that method only hides immediate parent. I need to hide a specific parent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `.parent()` method to select the parent node of specified child nodes, and use `.hide()` to hide the selected parent nodes.

```js
$('.childB').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
    A
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
    A
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childB">
    B
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
    A
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childB">
    B
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childA">
    A
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that method only hides immediate parent. I need to hide a specific parent.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, `$('.childA').parent().hide();`

Comment: this doesn't work because it only hides the immediate parent but my example was simplified; i need to hide it based on the class `.mainDiv`

Comment: that method only hides immediate parent. I need to hide a specific parent.

Answer (score 1):

Grab all div of mainDiv class and loop for each can check children class has specific class !!

```
var main = document.getElementsByClassName("mainDiv");
for(var i = 0; i < main.length ; i++){
    if(main[i].children[0].classList[0] == "childB"){ //assure only has one children
        main[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: it does have many children, my example was simplified, will this work if there are many children but i only want to hide if there is a child with the class `.childB`?